# Catching specific exceptions thrown in the API Controller

Tags: c#, try-catch

I'm working on an API controller that needs to indicate if a request takes to long to get a response message from an external worker. To clarify to the user what has happened if that is the case, I want to throw a specific Exception back to the controller to handle, so I can give an appropiate message back to the user requesting.

The problem is if I try to throw a new TimeoutException, the try/catch doesn't pick up the specific exception by saying catch(TimeoutException e). But if I try to catch(Exception e), it works perfectly fine. I want to give another StatusCode returned if the connection times out (TimeoutException).

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Message>> ReceiveResponses(Guid id, int numberOfExpectedMessages)
    {
        CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        cts.CancelAfter(3000);
        
        while (numberOfExpectedMessages != Storage.GetMessagesSentCount(id))
        {
            Thread.Sleep(10);
            if (cts.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                cts.Dispose();
                throw new TimeoutException("The request timed out!");
            }
        }
        var messagesFound = Storage.GetMessagesFromMessagesReceived(id).ToList();
        Storage.RemoveMessageFromMessagesReceived(id);
        cts.Dispose();
        return messagesFound;
    }
}
```

//DocumentController:

```
        var response = _messageHandler.ReceiveResponses(id, 1).Result.First();

            return string.IsNullOrEmpty(response.Content)
                ? throw new Exception("Error when inserting query, check log!")
                : Ok(response.Content);
        }

        //doesn't work
        catch (TimeoutException e)
        {
            return StatusCode(500, e.Message);
        }
        //works
        //catch (Exception e)
        //{
        //  _log.Warning(e.Message);
        //  return StatusCode(500, e.Message);
        //}
    }
```

Example of response:
[image]

Comment: Are your TimeoutExceptions coming from the same namespace?

Comment: Same namespace, different folder. Tried moving them to the exact same namespace and folder, same error.

Comment: Based on the stack trace (which should be added as text instead of image), it looks like the `TimeoutException` is a nested exception under an `AggregateException`.  So controller would need to catch `AggregateException` and drill down, or change whatever is throwing the `AggregateException` to throw `TimeoutException`.

Comment: That seems to do the trick, tnaks for taking the time to answer @Andrew S